# JAVA GET API - 2D Array, Unable to retrieve?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am getting a data varilable through an API like this (notice square brackets):

```
[
    ["2018-09-03",287.5,289.8,286.15,287.3,287.65,1649749.0,4750.35],
    ["2018-08-31",286.25,290.5,285.0,285.5,285.95,3716997.0,10691.41],
    ["2018-08-30",286.45,290.55,284.6,286.05,285.6,3861403.0, 11097.03]
]
```

What I am doing wrong in the below script? I am new to Java and need to print this block in table. Please help me, thanks in advance

```
public class ArrayLoopTest{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String[] data = new String[
            ["2018-09-03",287.5,289.8,286.15,287.3,287.65,1649749.0,4750.35],
            ["2018-08-31",286.25,290.5,285.0,285.5,285.95,3716997.0,10691.41],
            ["2018-08-30",286.45,290.55,284.6,286.05,285.6,3861403.0, 11097.03]
        ];
        for (i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using an array keep in mind that array data structure can hold data of one type only. This essentially means that if a array is declared as String then it can have String type data only.

So, you can use the following code defining and printing the 2D array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    String[][] data = {
            {"2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"}      
            ,{"2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"}
            ,{"2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"}
    };


    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(data[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // or you can print like this

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data[i])+",");

    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can use the `com.google.gson` library as shown below to get a `2D array`:

```
//String apiResponse = get Api Response
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();    // parser converstthe api response to Json
JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(apiResponse);
JsonObject obj1 = obj.getAsJsonObject("dataset");
JsonArray arr = obj1.get("data").getAsJsonArray();

String[][] newString = new String[arr.size()][arr.get(0).getAsJsonArray().size()];

for(int i=0;i<newString.length;i++) {

            for(int j=0;j<newString[i].length;j++) {


                newString[i][j] = arr.get(i).getAsJsonArray().get(j).getAsString();

            }

        }


System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newString));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped. Just one issue with my original question:

I am getting the data as like below only from an API, How to convert it to the above mentioned array:

[
["2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"],
[ "2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"],[  "2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"]
]

Comment: @VivekBajpai there is no need to convert. This is also a 2d array only. Just traverse it using 2 for loops and you will be able to print it.

Comment: I tried it using sqaure brackets and it is giving error. With curly braces its okay but I am getting data in sqaure brackets.

Comment: @VivekBajpai Could you update the question with this info like the data and the corresponding error you are getting.

Comment: Updated the query. Please check, thanks for your help.

Comment: @VivekBajpai where is this API? Is it your local API or is deployed on some remote server?

Comment: This is the GET API and it has data element with multiple sets, I need those as a table view output.

https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/NSE/INFY.json?api_key=xqrxzz3xN9c3XbazKxLV&start_date=2018-08-03&end_date=2018-09-03

Comment: @VivekBajpai check my answer under Edit. You can convert the API response to JSON and then convert it into 2D array.

Comment: Superb, thx a lot dear. Thanks for all the help and patience.

Comment: @VivekBajpai please mark this answer as accepted if you found it helpful by clicking on accept sign to the left of answer under upvote and downvote sign.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wold of java.

Here are some things that you seem not to be doing well, as you know java is a strongly typed language. However from your code you are using a float in your array . perhaps you have declared that your array will contain strings only.

More so you are not declaring your array in a right way.
 I will recommend that you work through this tutorial quickly [Arrays in java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/).

But to resolve your issue you can do this instead

```
p

ublic static void main(String []args){
            String[][] data = new String[][]{

                {"2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"},
                    {"2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"},
                    {"2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"},

            };



            for (int i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].lenght(); i++){
`                        System.out.print(data[i][j] + "  ");
                      }
                      System.out.println("--------------")


            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped. Just one issue with my original question:

I am getting the data as like below only from an API, How to convert it to the above mentioned array:

[
["2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"],
[ "2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"],[  "2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"]
]

Comment: I do not understand your question. Ok so you are saying you are getting a float and a string from an  api? Or what do  you mean. More so can I see you API payload, I doubt any API will send this. API responses are always strings.

Answer (score 0):

This won't compile as your array isn't of the correct format and the variable i is not defined. You need to loop over the items in each subarray and print them instead.

```
String[][] data = new String[][]{
    { "2018-09-03", "287.5", "289.8", "286.15", "287.3", "287.65", "1649749.0", "4750.35" },
    { "2018-08-31", "286.25", "290.5", "285.0", "285.5", "285.95", "3716997.0", "10691.41" },
    { "2018-08-30", "286.45", "290.55", "284.6", "286.05", "285.6", "3861403.0", "11097.03" }
};
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped. Just one issue with my original question:

I am getting the data as like below only from an API, How to convert it to the above mentioned array:

[
["2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"],
[ "2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"],[  "2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"]
]

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in two ways, one dimensional and two dimensional, if you are thinking to put different data types in a single array, that is not possible in java.You can put only one type of data type inside defined array type.

**Two dimensional array code:**

```
public class ArrayLoopTest{

 public static void main(String []args){
     String[][] data = 
     {
        {"2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"},
        { "2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"},
        {  "2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"}
     };
    for (int i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
    {
        for(int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(data[i][j]+" "); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }

 }}
```

**One dimensional array code**

```
public class ArrayLoopTest{
public static void main(String []args){
     String[] data ={"2018-09-03,287.5,289.8,286.15,287.3,287.65,1649749.0,4750.35",
                     "2018-08-31,286.25,290.5,285.0,285.5,285.95,3716997.0,10691.41",
                     "2018-08-30,286.45,290.55,284.6,286.05,285.6,3861403.0, 11097.03"};
    for (int i=0;i < data.length;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
 }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped. Just one issue with my original question:

I am getting the data as like below only from an API, How to convert it to the above mentioned array:

[
["2018-09-03","287.5","289.8","286.15","287.3","287.65","1649749.0","4750.35"],
[ "2018-08-31","286.25","290.5","285.0","285.5","285.95","3716997.0","10691.41"],[  "2018-08-30","286.45","290.55","284.6","286.05","285.6","3861403.0", "11097.03"]
]